# Break points of load testing

Tags: load-testing

My application is overloaded or not able to do actions after some time what type of errors we will have and how do we identify breakpoints of application with the load test. what types of tests we can do to identify breakpoints. thanks in advance

Comment: What language? What application type? What is an architecture? What do you call *load*? Is it web requests? is it DB application? is it worker? What is that? Do you expect that all systems are designed same way? and can be tested and diagnosed with the same  set of tools and techniques?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to overload a web front end application you can try set up concurrent users in a selenium test and seeing how it might break.

If you're wanting to test back end applications then you could write unit / integration tests in a multi-threaded approach and hit it with a lot of queries.

Your question does however need to be a bit more specific or provide some additional info though.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main performance testing types:

1. [Load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing#Software_load_testing) - when you put the system under **anticipated** load, i.e. exactly mimic its real usage by real users and check whether it is capable of supporting X concurrent users providing reasonable response time
2. [Stress testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) - when you identify the application under test boundaries and breaking points by putting it under heavier load. I.e. start from anticipated number of users (if you don't have an "anticipated" number - start from 1) and **gradually** increase the load at the same time keeping an eye on [performance metrics](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites).

   Ideally when you increase the load by factor of 2x the throughput (number of requests per second) should increase by the same factor. When you increase the load but throughput does not increase it means that you found so called [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) - it is basically the maximum number of users your system can **efficiently** support prior to degradation.

   If you continue increasing the load you will observe increased response time. Also errors can start occurring. When response starts exceeding the maximum defined in [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) - you can call this "breaking point".

There is also one more "interesting" performance testing type - [Soak Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) which is basically the same as Load Testing (or a little bit more users) but for **prolonged** period of time, this way you can detect the majority of [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).